# Undo a text insertion through button click event in windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a small windows form application in C#. I have a lot of buttons and a combobox, which upon being clicked add certain text at the current cursor position in a rich text box. Is there any way to undo this text insertion?. I have tried the richTextBox.Undo() method but it only works if the most recent text added to the rich text box is via key board. But if it's through the buttons or the combobox then nothing happens and what's more is that the cursor also disappears.
This is my method to add text on button click and I want it to be undone on clicking the undo button or CTRL+Z

```
    private void mybuttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // ---------- Method for inserting tags on clicking the POS Tags buttons ---------- //

        Button btn = (Button)sender; // receiving information about which button was clicked.
        string strInsert = "<" + btn.Text + ">" + " "; // inseting '<>' and an extra space at the end of the tag

        // inserting the tag at the current cursor position.

        richTextBox1.Focus();
        int i = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(richTextBox1.SelectionStart, strInsert);
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i + strInsert.Length;

        // moving the cursor to the next word to be tagged.

        richTextBox1.Focus();
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{LEFT}");
    }
```

Help needed.

Regards!

Comment: Sorry for the "an text".... it's simple "text" without the "an"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a
   `List<string>`
so the list will  keep track of the inserts and rollback to undo.

Answer (score 1):

There are several "[Undo managers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:codeproject.com%20undo%20manager)" available on The Code Project, e.g. [this one here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10947/A-simple-framework-for-adding-undo-redo-support) that has an example with a text box:

[image]

If I would have to solve it, I would download the example and see how I can adjust it to fit my own requirements.

Comment: +1, learning by example usually helps me very much in such cases

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a variable with

1. the number of characters entered, or
2. the string recently added (in case your like to CTRL+y what you have CTRL+z'ed).

Also, if you'd like to have a multi step CTRL+z, you declare

```
List<String> additions = ...
```

instead and play around .Add(...)'ing and .Remove(...)'ing elements to/from the list.

Comment: I know that some people go string instead of String but i'd still argus that since it's an object and not a native, it should be capitalized. I'll be probably counterargued on this one but until then, let me enjoy it.

Comment: `string` is a C# built-in type.  `String` is a .NET type.  `string` maps to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Undo/Redo is not easy.  There are many different approaches out there, but typically, they all boil down to a Stack, that keeps track of actions performed by the user. To undo, you pop the most recent action, and perform some method to undo that action.

In the case of text, I would do something like this:

1. Record what text is in the box first.
2. On keypress, start/reset a timer (say 0.5 sec).
3. When the timer expires (the user paused typing), store off the old text in some "Undo Action"
4. Push that action onto the undo stack

When you want to "undo", simply restore the text in the textbox to whatever was recorded in step 0.